# Concatenate php as html id

Tags: php, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate $firstname and $lastname as a select box id. Where am I going wrong?

```
echo '<td>
<select name="'$firstname.$lastname'" id="'$firstname.$lastname'">
       <option selected disabled>Select Action</option>
   <option value="activate">Activate User</option>
       <option value="delete">Delete User</option>
   <option value="admin">Admin</option>
</select>
  </td>';
```

Comment: You should be getting _syntax error, unexpected '$firstname' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';'_. You need to concat the string with the vars too, so `.. name="' . $firstname.$lastname . '" id="' . $firstname.$lastname . '">..`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add concatenators before and after the first and last name:

```
<select name="'.$firstname.$lastname.'" id="'.$firstname.$lastname.'">
```

Answer (score 3):

Your concatenation is incorrect. Use the following:

```
echo '<td>
 <select name="'.$firstname.$lastname.'" id="'.$firstname.$lastname.'">
       <option selected disabled>Select Action</option>
   <option value="activate">Activate User</option>
       <option value="delete">Delete User</option>
   <option value="admin">Admin</option>
 </select>
</td>';
```

Comment: Yes thanks a lot missed the concatenation before the variable.